# Extract multiple protein sequences from a Protein Data Bank along with Secondary Structure

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, protein-database

I want to extract protein sequences and their corresponding secondary structure from any Protein Data bank, say RCSB. I just need short sequences and their secondary structure. Something like,

```
ATRWGUVT     Helix
```

It is fine even if the sequences are long, but I want a tag at the end that denotes its secondary structure. Is there any programming tool or anything available for this.

As I've shown above I want only this much minimal information. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please see [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) on writing a good StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DSSP](http://swift.cmbi.ru.nl/gv/dssp/).

The output of DSSP is explained extensively under '[explanation](http://swift.cmbi.ru.nl/gv/dssp/DSSP_3.html)'. The very short summary of the output is:

```
H = α-helix
B = residue in isolated β-bridge
E = extended strand, participates in β ladder
G = 3-helix (310 helix)
I = 5 helix (π-helix)
T = hydrogen bonded turn
S = bend
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from Bio.PDB import *
from distutils import spawn
```

Extract sequence:

```
def get_seq(pdbfile):
 p = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=0)
 structure = p.get_structure('test', pdbfile)
 ppb = PPBuilder()
 seq = ''
 for pp in ppb.build_peptides(structure):
  seq += pp.get_sequence()

 return seq
```

Extract secondary structure with DSSP as explained earlier:

```
def get_secondary_struc(pdbfile):
    # get secondary structure info for whole pdb.
    if not spawn.find_executable("dssp"):
        sys.stderr.write('dssp executable needs to be in folder')
        sys.exit(1)
    p = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=0)
    ppb = PPBuilder()
    structure = p.get_structure('test', pdbfile)
    model = structure[0]
    dssp = DSSP(model, pdbfile)
    count = 0
    sec = ''
    for residue in model.get_residues():
        count = count + 1
        # print residue,count
        a_key = list(dssp.keys())[count - 1]
        sec += dssp[a_key][2]
    print sec
    return sec
```

This should print both sequence and secondary structure.